# What is a "typical" in the context of control engineering?

Tags: control-engineering, terminology

When talking about control systems I sometimes hear the term "typical", however I have no clear understanding what it is. It's also mentioned in some codes (so far without definition), here's an example image from the DIN EN 62424 (IEC 62424:2016):

[image]

From context, I think that it refers to software building blocks or common functions of the device (sensor or actor) itself but I'm not sure. We don't have a control engineer in house whom I could ask.

I tried googling the term but typical is such a common word.

Edit to add: I wondered if "typical" is a weird anglicism, but found this in the DIN:
[image]

"Acronym and identification of a grafical diagram in a database, or group of signals or grouped PCE-tasks"

It doesnt really answer my question what a tpyical does or is for.

Comment: About the same as "average" when you hear average man or average woman...

Comment: you do know that you don't *have* to comment on every question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a bit difficult to find anything about it, it strikes me like some odd anglicism (just like Germans call mobile phone "Handy").
I managed to find a definition in [this](http://ww3.cad.de/foren/ubb/uploads/AF/2_dokstruct_evu_2005_07_10.pdf) document:

> Typical: Ein nicht konkret zu Strukturen der Anlage zugeordneter
> Dokumentensatz, der normalerweise für mehrere Anlagenteile (Objekte in
> der Struktur der Anlage) gilt und auf den von anderen Dokumenten
> verwiesen wird.

Own English translation:

> Typical: A set of documents that does not belong directly to the structures of
> one particular plant. It is usually valid for multiple parts of a
> plant (objects in the plant structure) and referred to by other
> documents.

Comment: I would translate the first sentence as "A set of documents that do not belong zu particular structures of the plant". Good find!

Comment: chapter 4.3 of the linked document explains a bit more. I'll wait a bit, but I think this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Optical resonators answer is correct. However here's an illustrative example I found:

[image]

The part in the cloud is "typical 11", the number "11" to the left of the motor's bubble in the lower right tells us that all the stuff in the cloud is implemented with this motor:

- local start/stop
- remote stop
- remote displays for current, Fault, runtime